# Why is the character & replaced by "et"?

Tags: french

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,fleqn,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1]{\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\markboth{{#1}}{{#1}}}
% Set the beginning of a LaTeX document
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{makeidx} % allows for indexgeneration
\usepackage[-20pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=3.2cm,vmargin=4.6cm, rmargin=3.2cm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\usepackage{txfonts} \usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\newcommand{\lesss}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\land$}}
\newcommand{\less}{\ \lesss\ }
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{caption}
\hyphenation{prépos-si-tions}

\renewcommand{\&}{et}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage{Packages/phs_goodies}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}  % à activer pour version française
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

I write this sentence in french

```
Barker and Cornacchia ont proposé le système \textit{B} \& \textit{C}
```

But it display

> Barker and Cornacchia ont proposé le système B et C

i.e., the "&" is replaced by "et". Why

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it is part from a thesis with each chapter in one file

Comment: `\renewcommand{\&}{et}` what is this doing in your document?

Comment: Since this is some template you found online, here is the truth: It isn't good. Better start with [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports)

Comment: unless you have a need to emulate documents written for latex2.09 in the 1980s don't load `epsfig`

Comment: Unrelated: `epsfig`\  has been obsolete for more than 20 years. It is simply replaced with `graphicx`. The `french` option of `babel` is already loaded with the document class (that's the right place). `txfonts` should be replaced with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, `slashbox` with `diagbox`. As to hyphenation, *prépossitions* are not *prépositions*…

Comment: you are specifying lots of packages twice. amsmath,algorithm,algorithmic

Comment: `et` is `and` in French. `&` is generally pronounced `and`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are explicitly asking to LaTeX to do this in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\&}{et}
```

Just remove this line and `\&` will print &

## Edit:

If you are absolutely, completely, 100% sure you want *all* instances of *&* replaced by *et*, except in this sentence you can put `\let\oldamp\&` before the `\renewcommand` and write:

```
Barker and Cornacchia ont proposé le système \textit{B} \oldamp\ \textit{C}
```

Comment: you are right this is the problem, i used this command for the  bibliographie, because when a refrence contain & with style apacite i replaced it with "et", is there any solution to use it \& in only this sentetce as &

Comment: If you want to replace `&` by `et` in the bibliography you can move the `\renewcommand` right before the `\bibliography`.

Comment: i don't understand where to add the command \renewcommand{\&}{et}, because when I write it juts before  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{VersionFinaleThese} it doesn't work

Comment: You are correct, it is before the `\bibliography{VersionFinaleThese}`. When you say "bibliography" you mean the final chapter that contains the references, or are you talking about the citation in the middle of the text? Because I tested here and it does work with the references .-.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked with the command \let\oldamp\&
\renewcommand{\&}{et}